# (iphone) can i make UIScrollView to recognize horizontal dragging only?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, touch

I'm using UIScrollView's canceling touch ability with canCancelContentTouches.

However, I 'd like the uiscrollview to attempt to cancel touch when it detected horizontal dragging(not vertical).

(Hope solution would be available under < iOS 3.13)

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Implement the `UIScrollViewDelegate` and then use something like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [scrollView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y)];
}
```

Another way would be having a UIScrollView which is smaller or equal to the size of its parent view and with a disabled "Always bounce horizontal".

Answer (score 1):

The safest and most successful method I've found to constrain the movement of a scroll view is to subclass **UIScrollView** and override **setContentOffset:animated:** and **setContentOffset:** methods (code below).

The advantage of overriding these methods is that it directly alters the requested **contentOffset** before any of the UIKit code starts to act on it, avoiding any of the side effects that can occur when modifying the contentOffset in **scrollViewDidScroll:** or other **UIScrollViewDelegate** methods.

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated {
    // restrict movement to horizontal only
    CGPoint newOffset = CGPointMake(contentOffset.x, 0);
    [super setContentOffset:newOffset animated:animated];
}

- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset {
    // restrict movement to horizontal only
    CGPoint newOffset = CGPointMake(contentOffset.x, 0);
    [super setContentOffset:newOffset];    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess i would use the method **scrollViewWillBeginDragging** 
found in the UIScrollViewDelegate
and inside i could control if user is going horizontally or not...

scrollViewWillBeginDragging:

Tells the delegate when the scroll view is about to start scrolling the content.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

Parameters

**scrollView**

The scroll-view object that is about to scroll the content view.

**Discussion**

The delegate might not receive this message until dragging has occurred over a small distance.

**Availability
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.**